# Safari developer tools not showing custom CSS when debugging Ipad

Tags: css, ios, safari, safari-web-inspector

When I use the Safari Developers Tools to debug CSS on an iPad I can't see the custom styles.

[image]

Debugging the same website in Safari on Mac, I can see the styling just fine.

[image]

Am I missing a setting or is not possible?

I am using iOS 14 on the iPad